# Unable to install packages in atom(Ubuntu 17.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu, atom-editor

I was trying to install the script package in atom on Ubuntu 17.04 both via command line and GUI. 
The installation fails giving me the result-
undefined
Whats the issue?
This is happening for other packages as well.
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df3lI.png)

Comment: What version of Atom are you using?

Comment: I am using atom 1.18.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few bugs recently, which have been fixed in the latest release.  If you installed it with `apt-get`, remove it with:
`apt-get remove --purge atom`.

Then go to https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.18.0
and download the latest release for debian/ubuntu.  Install that and then (hopefully), you should be able to install packages again.